# Copy content of one array to another arry

Tags: javascript, arrays

#### How I can write javascript code that can copy content of one array into another array twice?

Example:

```
   Array A = [1,2,3,4];
```

This array is passed to one function. Define new array in that function and write a code that will copy content of array A into new array twice, So new Array will be like below.

```
 newArray = [1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4].
```

Thank you.

Comment: That's not how you create an array in javascript. Please post what have you tried so far.

Comment: Sounds like an assignment. The purpose of the assignment is likely that *you* are coming up with a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest to go with `guest271314` answer. But if you want to multiply it more than twice, and you're looking for an alternative solution, you can also do it like,

```
var arr = [1,2,3,4];

var dupeTimes = 2;
var newArr = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(arr).repeat(dupeTimes).replace(/\]\[/g, ','))
console.log(newArr); // [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4]

dupeTimes = 10;
newArr = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(arr).repeat(dupeTimes).replace(/\]\[/g, ','))
console.log(newArr); // [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: thanks, Looking for generic solution... While posing question I did not care about syntax.. Just tried to explain as much as I could....

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array.prototype.concat()`

```js
var A = [1, 2, 3, 4];
var res = A.concat(A);
console.log(A, res);
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, Your syntax is not right. Refer the below Code which is from `MDN`

```
var vegetables = ['parsnip', 'potato'];
var moreVegs = ['celery', 'beetroot'];

// Merge the second array into the first one
// Equivalent to vegetables.push('celery', 'beetroot');
Array.prototype.push.apply(vegetables, moreVegs);

console.log(vegetables); // ['parsnip', 'potato', 'celery', 'beetroot']
```

[MDN: Merging Two Arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push#Merging_two_arrays)

In your case. you can do like below.

```
var A = [1,2,3,4];
Array.prototype.push.apply(A, A);
```

```js
var A = [1,2,3,4];
Array.prototype.push.apply(A, A);
console.log(A);
```

Start take Tutorial before posting basic question. Below tutorial website can help you for basic JS.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/

Answer (score 0):

Default array     'arr=[1,2,3,4,5]'    this will be copied to the     'newarr'    through the function     'arrcopy()'

```
var arr=[1,2,3,4,5];
    var newarray=[],na=[];
    function arrcopy(na){
      for(var i=0;i<2;i++){
        for(var j=0;j<na.length;j++){
          newarray[(i*na.length)+j]=na[j];
        }
      }
      alert(newarray);
    }
    arrcopy(arr);
```

NOTE:there are really simpler ways to do this with just built-in functions...